# Firebase Firestore Console reads

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase and on the console I get very high reads, does anyone know what it is and how can it be solved? And I read that it may be because I leave the console open, if by reason they refer to the firebase page in the console, I always leave it closed. If anyone knows or has a problem like that please help me. Thanks

[Firebase Firestore reads Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJFuC.png)

[Firestore Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nksxB.png)

[Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1EoN.png)

Here you can see that 2 days ago i used to have only a few reads, look...
[Reads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bciYp.png)

UPDATE: In the rules I have it in test mode, it says that while it is in test mode, "third party reads and writes" will be allowed. If I put it in production mode, will the reads be reduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Firestore depends on Two (Read , Write) .. The means If anyone have your API he can Read or Write Data to Your Database So I would like to do some Security Steps :

- You must change your Firestore Security Rules from Test Rules to
  Production if you your site is live hosted on domain So it is highly
  recommend to edit Your Rules for better experience (Also as fast as
  possible) Also if you didn't update your rules after 30 days from creating DB , Firebase
  will close all read & write (This means your app won't read or write)
  So change it fast
- If your project connected to Google Cloud Platform .. You can setup
  Google Cloud Platform HTTP that mean (Firebase will only accept
  read & Write from your own domain that you will setup) As if anyone
  read from you DB so it will be denied

**Note** : if you work on your site from localhost or local file it will be denied too

Also high reads mean a lot of user reads So if user refresh the page a lot it will be calculated as read as example below :

I visited your site (1 Read) .. I refreshed page (1 Read) Refreshed page again (1 Read) .. Again (1 Read) .. Again (1 Read) .. So if you calculated you will see it will be 5 reads for just refreshing page times

I would be clear in my answer & help you So if you have questions feel free to ask me in comments .. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot!

My rules are like this right now:

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
   match / databases / {database} / documents {
     match / {document = **} {
       allow read, write: if
           request.time <timestamp.date (2021, 4, 29);
     }
   }
}

Do I need to change them like this?

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
   match / databases / {database} / documents {
     match / {document = **} {
       allow read, write: if false
     }
   }
}

Comment: @SantiagoPadilla You current rules are Puplic & Also in Test Mode So anyone have access to your DB .. Second rules also Very Strong (Very Strong mean it will denied all access for your DB even your app won't work) .. I can help you just if you send screenshoot with your DB Structure and I will help you create rules

Comment: @SantiagoPadilla Also Security Rules depends on Your DB Structure and How you use Cloud Firestore

Comment: So I just have to change the rules from public to private. I do that from the console or from DB Structure? I am very new to this and I don't know where the DB Structure is. Thanks for the help